# asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument python

Tags: python, postgresql, counter, jsonb, asyncpg

I have a problem insert to PostgreSQL.
The column I'm trying to insert is of type JSONB.
The type of the object is `Counter()`.

In production it is working, but locally it raises the following error:

> **asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $16: Counter({'clearmeleva': 1, 'cr7fragrance... (expected str, got
> Counter)**

Thank you!

Comment: covert it to a dictionary first

Comment: @gold_cy but it is working in prod without convert to dict ..

Comment: Btw, convert to dict didnt solve this problem

Comment: Please add some context to your question. Which versions of asyncpg are you using in production and locally? How did you istantiate your Counter object? Which line of code is throwing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [asyncpg documentation](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html#type-conversion), the corresponding Python type for `JSON` and `JSONB` is a `string`.
So if the column where you want to add your data is of type `JSONB`, try to convert your `Counter-type` object to a `string`

```
new_counter_type_obj = str(counter_type_obj)
```

and then pass it to asyncpg.